# Bevel modifier doesn't do anything

Tags: bevel

If I try to apply Bevel modifier to Object - nothing happens, changing Amount, Segments.. Only "Absolute" Width type actually adds tiny bevel but I can't change neither the Amount, only Segments.
If I try to do it manually, by selecting all and CTRL+B it bevels all the edges. I would want it to act like Bevel Modifier. What could be fix for Bevel Modifier, or how to set the CTRL+B to bevel only Edges like Bevel modifier would do, sharp edges.

Comment: Try to uncheck *Clamp Overlap* in *Geometry* section

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clamp Overlap option prevent two bevels overlap each other. Basically it clamps bevel width by the shortest distance between two beveling edges:

[image]

If disabling Clamp Overlap reveals bevels, try to remove vertexes that's close to each other.

Select all - press <kbd>M</kbd> ⇾ **By distance** may help

Comment: It solved. Thanks!