# Cant Work Out Why Bevel Modifier Doesn't Work

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I am trying to create a model of the bridge following a tutorial and have almost finished creating the bridge's towers, however, for some reason, I cannot make the bevel modifier work no matter what. I have tried to merge the vertices with "M" and a bunch of other settings, making sure that nothing overlaps but nothing seems to work. I am a beginner, so kindly ask someone to point what exactly am I doing wrong?

[image]

[Link to the project file](https://pasteall.org/blend/6917c094dda844c0a088a319f6e604ed)

Comment: Your normals may not be calculated correctly. Even if they are, I would disable the modifier’s “Clamp overlap” option.

Comment: "Clamp overlap" was the solution thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Your welcome. PS: found a duplicate with a clear answer  https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/215942/73575